# How to make a button appear after a certain level?

Tags: ios

So to add levels I use integer +100 "then a certain number"

But now I want to add a button lets say, to appear after integer 101 out of 120,

What would e.g set the button hidden, then show it when user gets the level 101,

How would I do that?

The code below is just an example of the integer!

```
((UIButton*)[Puzzle viewWithTag:[[[lstWord objectAtIndex: theCurrentWord]objectAtIndex:bt.tag-201] integerValue]+122]).hidden = FALSE;
[[lstWord objectAtIndex:theCurrentWord]replaceObjectAtIndex:bt.tag-201 withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",-1]];
```

Comment: im afraid i dont understand, and your code just added to my confusion. `hidden`is in fact the correct property to hide a button, but you need to set it to `YES`, not `FALSE` to hide the button. What happens when you run this code? Where does it fail, and how?

Answer (score 0):

What I can think of is some kind of game loop, and you check the value of your integer every frame.

Or, perhaps an NSTimer that repeats the check.